# CouchDB: View to return only certain documents?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have (tried) to write a view to identify documents with an "otherCauseForRelease" attribute AND that attribute is actually populated.  My View code is:

```
function (doc) {
if(doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease.length > 5);  emit(doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease);
}
```

However, the return set includes documents with attribute values like "" (an open double-quotation followed by a close double-quotation).  How can I exclude these documents from my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one here :

function (doc) {
     if(doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease.length > 5)
         emit(doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease);
     }

You basically add an extra `;` at the end of your if. Doing so, it didn't consider the next statement as the body of the if.

Another example with curly braces:

```
function (doc) {
 if(doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease.length > 5){
     emit(doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it seems I had malformed syntax.  Alexis' solution worked.  Additionally, I was able to apply field lables by enclosing my "emit" in another pair of braces: ----- 

       {emit({"Primary": doc.payload.causeForRelease, "Secondary":     doc.payload.otherCauseForRelease});}

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you